# How do I highlight a term with an underbrace?

Tags: math-mode, highlighting

I would like to highlight my equation in this way:

[image: Figure]

I'm using an align environment. Could you help me?

Comment: Use `underbrace` command.

Comment: In future it would be good manners (and help you get your answer sooner) if you provided the code for the bits that you can do - ideally all of those integrals above the } to save some poor soul from typing it all out for you, adding the packages and so on and so forth

Comment: @manooooh This worked perfecly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks also to the comments and observations of the very good users, I have recreated exactly with LaTeX, your formula.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\[
+\underbrace{\int \mathrm{d}^3 r\int\mathrm{d}^3 \bm{r}'n_1(\bm{r})
V_{\mathrm{dd}}(\bm{r},\bm{r}')n_2 r'}_{\equiv E_{\mathrm{int} }}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well played :P You beat me by seconds :) +1

Comment: Although, you haven't respected the author's fonts (bold, upright and so on), might i recommend `\[
  + \underbrace{\int \mathrm{d}^{3}r \int \mathrm{d}^{3}r'\
    n_{1}(\bm{r})V_{\mathrm{dd}} (\bm{r}, \bm{r}')n_{2}(\bm{r}')}_{\equiv
    E_{\text{int}}}
\]`

Comment: Almost the same. The `r` in OP's picture are bold and the last `r'` in parentheses :) Also, don't use the `minimal` class.

Comment: Cool, no downvote so far. ;-) +1 ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I honestly didn't realize that the R's were bold and italic. I have inserted the addendum.

Comment: @marmot AHAHHAH...You can't know yet, because it's too early. Are we betting that someone will vote negatively? :-)

Comment: @Au101 ahahahahhh ... when you wrote to me I was thinking about the profile of the very good egreg. He is faster than the speed of light.

Comment: @Sebastiano No problem. I pointed out just to improve the answer ;) +1

Comment: I have upvoted all your comment and +1 to the new OP. Best regards to everybody.

Comment: Hey @Sebastiano, I think you added the `+` inside the under brace when the image show that it's outside. `:)`

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of removing the unneeded `\mathit` "wrappers"; feel free to revert.

Comment: The + sign should be outside `\underbrace`.

Comment: @egreg Dear and kind egreg, with all my heart I have not really seen it.

Comment: @Mico You are always allowed to change everything I do and my mistakes. Thank you very much.

Comment: @manooooh Thank you very much, but I didn't see it well. Thank you I have just made the change.